# How can I add horizontal-space in between columns, when using python to append several lists onto a file?

Tags: python

```
for item in zip(xcoords, ycoords, zcoords):  
    out = open("file.txt", "a")  
    print (item)  
    out.write( "Ar" "%s %s %s \n" %(item))  
    out.close()
```

I want all four columns to be separate from each other. Currently my code prints,

```
Ar123   
Ar213   
Ar312
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding a space like this:

```
    for item in zip(xcoords, ycoords, zcoords):
    out = open("file.txt", "a")
    print (item)
    out.write( "Ar" " " "%s " " %s " " %s \n" %(item))
    out.close()
```

Note that I added extra space by putting " " in between.

Comment: Had typed an answer out, But you beat me to it! +1

Answer (score 2):

Don't keep opening the file in the loop,open outside and you can use csv.writer with izip_longets to write all the rows:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
import csv

with open("file.txt", "a") as out:
    wr = csv.writer(out, delimiter=" ")
    wr.writerows(izip_longest(["Ar"],x, y, z,fillvalue="Ar"))
```

If you want to add `Ar` `str.format`:

```
with open("file.txt", "a") as out:
    for item in zip(xcoords, ycoords, zcoords):
        out.write("Ar {} {} {}\n".format(*item))
```

Or unpack and use writerow:

```
import csv
with open("file.txt", "a") as out:
    wr = csv.writer(f, delimiter=" ")
    for x, y, z in zip(xcoords, ycoords, zcoords):
        wr.writerow(["Ar", x, y, z])
```